# Mysql - Stuck on a single row's value for all rows?

Tags: mysql, row, alias

I am having an issue with mysql where an inner select statement is always being evaluated with the first row of the outer table.  In the following code, "WHERE otherTable.someID = myTable1.table1_id" should (in my mind) match the outer myTable1.table1_id that is initially selected.  That is, each row of table1 is processed, but the inner myTable1.table1_id seems to always be stuck on the first row of table1 resulting in correct output for the first row but incorrect for all subsequent rows.

Its as if I replaced the inner myTable1.table1_id with the actual value of the first row's ID and ran that query.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
  myTable1.table1_id, 
  ..., 
  (SELECT otherStuff FROM otherTable WHERE otherTable.someID = myTable1.table1_id)
FROM table1 myTable1 
ORDER BY myTable1.table1_id;
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to do a simple join:

```
SELECT 
  myTable1.table1_id, 
  ..., 
  otherstuff from othertable
FROM table1 myTable1 join othertable on myTable1.table1_id=othertable.some_ID
ORDER BY myTable1.table1_id;
```

If you need to get back result rows even when othertable doesn't contain a matching ID, change the join to a `left join`.

Comment: What if myTable1 and otherTable are separate instances of the same table (i.e. both are "table1")?

Comment: Is not a problem, but you need to alias the references to the table eg.SELECT * FROM tabel1 t1 join table1 t2 WHERE t1.ref=t2.parentref